# Operation with time series

Tags: r, time, series

I have a time series A (`ts_A`) from 1902 to 2014, frequency=12, with value for each month and some year (and consequently month) with `NA` value.

```
ts_A 

 year gen feb mar ... dec  
 1902 300 525 652     524
 1903 NA  NA  NA  ...  NA
 .... ... ... ... ... ...
 2014 742 135 699 586 458
```

However i have another time series (`ts_B`) from 1902 to 2014, frequency=1 (yearly distribution)

```
year value
1902  6524
1903  5682
....  ....
2014  5984
```

I would take the data `NA` in `ts_A`, only when in `ts_B` the value for that year is present, because later I will substitute them with a proportion.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Please show reproducible examples.

Comment: can is: what?  Please update in your post

Comment: Sorry..can you look my answer. (1 answer)

Comment: IMPORTANT: the data have the same nature, for ts_A the distribution is for month, in ts_B the distribution is for year. The problem is that in the ts_B there are some annual value not present montly in ts_A.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me (or others, apparently) what exactly you want, but I think it's something along the lines of this:

1. find rows/years in `ts_A` that have all `NA`'s;
2. find rows/years in `ts_B` that are also `NA`;
3. extract/use only the all-`NA` rows/years in `ts_A` where the same row/year in `ts_B` is not `NA`.

If so, then something like this will work.

```
# make some dummy data
set.seed(123)
ts_A <- data.frame(seq(2000,2014),matrix(rpois(180,450),ncol=12))
colnames(ts_A) <- c("year",month.abb)
ts_B <- data.frame(year=seq(2000,2014),value=apply(ts_A[,-1],1,sum))

# pretend N years in ts_A have NA for all months
N <- 3
knock_out <- sample(ts_A$year,N)
ts_A[ts_A$year %in% knock_out,-1] <- rep(NA,12)
# make one of the years in ts_B also NA
ts_B[ts_B$year %in% knock_out[1],-1] <- NA

# these are the rows/years in ts_A that either have data or a non-NA in ts_B
ts_C <- ts_A[!(is.na(ts_B$value) & apply(is.na(ts_A[,-1]),1,all)),]
```